# Overload or Override int method() for toString() formatted output?

Tags: java

I have a class that stores a number in the millions.  What I would like to do is override the method to get that number and apply a string formatter for readable UIX output.

This is what I have to "overload" the to gets:

```
class dudViewModel {
    public int gettotal () {
        return this.total;
    }
    public String gettotal(String formated) {
        return String.format("%.1f", (float)total / 1000000);
    }   
}
```

So it's the difference between the two following calls:

```
gettotal(); // returns 23,400,000

and

gettotal("formatted");  // returns 23.4
```

Is there a better way or pattern in java to overload an individual method() that returns a number and override i with a tostring() call somehow to overide default number return and instead return a formatted string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a method does, must be indicated in its name. In this case, the two methods should be named different rather than trying to overload, overloading should alter the processing, not the total effect or output.

```
class dud {
   public int getTotal () {return this.total;}
   public String getFormattedTotal() {return String.format("%.1f", (float)total / 1000000);} 
   public String getFormattedTotal(String customFormat) {return String.format(customFormat, (float)total / 1000000);}  
}
```

Comment: I agree and like this! My solution is a bit one off using the class as a view model that ingests/jackson mapped per json via a REST call. My web app is somewhat of a pass through so rather than create another object just for raw data I want to overload a formatted method for each data value for the UI to display.  The UI needs both raw and formatted so I wanted to consolidate the gray area from biz/prez.  Either way, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I think the best way is to separate the presentation from the business logic. In this approach, you'd just have a single `getTotal()` method returning `int`. A completely separate method of a separate class would take that `int` and format it for the UI.

Comment: I completely agree with you. However, I'm overloading a viewModel that is ingested from json so that model is passed to the view.  What I would like to avoid is having a data class from a presentation class since it's a lightweight pass-through.  Good call though!

Answer (score 2):

```
or patter in java to overload an individual method() that returns a number and override i with a tostring()
```

You can apply [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) which allows behavior to be added to an individual object, either statically or dynamically, without affecting the behavior of other objects from the same class

Comment: great idea with the decorator pattern Vikas!

Answer (score 1):

Separate the data from its representation and you can also test it in isolation.

```
class Dud {

   public int getTotal () {return this.total;}
}

class DudPresentation {

     private Dud dud;         

     public DudPresentation(Dud dud){
         this.dud = dud;
     }


     public String getTotal() {
         return getTotal("%.1f");
     }

     public String getTotal(String format) {
         int total = dud.getTotal();
         return String.format(format, (float)total / 1000000);
     }   

}
```

Comment: Yes, totally agree with you on this one. But the class is a view model and the view needs both numbers (raw and formatted). So rather than have the view (.jsp) make those formats i wanted to expose another formatted call as an overloaded/ovveride tostring().  Net net, I like your solution.